# Use Desktop webcam on Android AVD

Tags: android, camera, webcam

i'm developing an android app that needs to capture a camera picture,

is there any way to configure my AVD to use my conputer webcam on the emulator?

when i open the default camera app it shows me an squareanymation, can i use/configure the emulator/avd to use my computer webcam?

Answer (score 0):

I really can't think of a way to do this.

I would do the following:

During development, when debugging on an actual Device under adb, use the camera as normal. While debugging on an AVD, comment out your camera code and us a pre-taken a png to your app  that resembles/emulates the photo the camera would have taken. This would let you work on the picture analysis regardless of the camera, and finish your app without an actual ADB device, just AVDs. One you get ahold of a real device you can finish up.

On another note, if you are ready to go poking around in VMs, Android Kernels, and HALS, you could follow this article (http://bytecruft.blogspot.com/2011/05/alternative-to-android-emulator-and.html) which tells you how to setup Android X86 under VMWare or Virtualbox as an ADB Device. I'm sure setting up the host machine's webcam as a camera would be much easier that bay (VMWare device bridging comes pretty close).

Hope I helped.